# Update contents of a div element with animation styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a personal portfolio webpage with React and I'm trying to update the content of the div element but when the elements are updated, I want to involve styling, (like the old content to exit on the left and the new content to enter from the left) Sorry for my bad English.
[This is the part I'm trying to update and add styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGG0j.png)

I've tried to use the componentDidMount method with a function that changes the heading but I don't know how to add animations/styling...

```
export default class Home extends Component {
skills_section_update = () => {
    let heading = document.getElementById('heading');

    const headings = [
        {
            head: 'Web Development'
        },
        {
            head: 'Game Development'
        }
    ];
    const update_head = (index) => {
        heading.innerText = headings[index].head;
    };
    update_head(1);
}
componentDidMount = () => {
    setInterval(this.skills_section_update, 2000);
};
```

I'm new to React so any help would be much appreciated.
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are special methods to do this using React but I know that you can't animate the content of a DOM element using CSS. What I would recommend is to add the updated content in another DOM element next to your current `div` and then animate the two to make a nice transition.

You could, for example, do something like that:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover .content {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.original {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.next {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content original">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="content next">
    New content
  </div>
</div>
```